# Not understanding how to USE the fft library generated by altera's megacore library

Tags: vhdl, fft, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

Want to know what synthesizable VHDL code needs to be written in Quartus II to ***use*** the library. Note that the library has already been generated by the Megacore Wizard. I'm a complete beginner to FPGAs and VHDL so, apologies if this is obvious.

Comment: You should add some code of what you have done so far.

Comment: We have an input to an ADC which stores data in registers. We want to perform an FFT on it. Didn't think that would be of any help here.

Comment: That's not code... What VHDL have you written sofar?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with an FFT IP core is quite a challenge if you have little to no experience with FPGAs of VHDL. You should start with a simple entity and simulation. Use an online tutorial.

MATLAB simulink and the HDL coder can help you make a design. The [Xilinx] HLS (high-level synthesis) C/C++ to HDL converter also can make you life easier.
In both cases there will be a learning curve.

As for the Altera FFT megacore: you should really read the [official user guide](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_fft.pdf). This states that you can actually have the core generator generate a testbench, which will show you how to instantiate the core.